# Trigger or invoke Chrome extension from mime type

Tags: google-chrome-extension

I'm in the process of writing a Google Chrome extension, specifically a lightweight EPUB reader, with the goal of it being just about as slick as the built in PDF reader in Chrome.

What I'm trying to figure out is if you can somehow trigger the extension *automagically* when you click a link that would normally force you to save an epub file to disk.

In a perfect world every link to an epub file would point to a `file.epub` and you'd be able to use a content script to point that to the extension, but unfortunately more often than not that's not the case. So what I'm thinking is that it would have to be triggered after the HTTP get request has returned the headers at least, and trigger off of the mime type via a `chrome.webRequest` or something.

Can you invoke a Google Chrome extension from the mime-type of a file being served to you?

Comment: To my knowledge, there is no currently a possibility to register your extension as specific file-type processor. Your option is indeed to intercept web-requests and if you detect epub file (by file extension or Content-Type header `application/epub`), copy the URL and open it in new tab under control of your extension. More simple way is to add your command into `contextMenus` and act on links to ebups.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are having browser action for all the functionality, you can detect and enable\disable extension with [chrome.webRequest.onHeadersReceived](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/webRequest.html#event-onHeadersReceived), [chrome.browserAction.enable()](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/browserAction.html#method-enable) and [chrome.browserAction.disable()](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/browserAction.html#method-disable)

**Pseudo Code**

***manifest.json***

```
{
  "name": "Detect Mime type",
  "version": "1.0",
  "description": "Detecting Mime type and enabling browser action",
  "permissions": ["webRequest", "webRequestBlocking",
                  "<all_urls>"],
  "background": {
    "scripts": ["background.js"]
  },
  "browser_action":{
    "default_popup":"popup.html", // Use you related code here
    "default_icon":"icon.jpg"
  },    
  "manifest_version": 2
}
```

***background.js***

```
chrome.webRequest.onHeadersReceived.addListener(function (object){
    // Do your code for related header(s)
    //Invoke chrome.browserAction.enable(integer tabId) or chrome.browserAction.disable(integer tabId)
},{urls: ["<all_urls>"]});
chrome.tabs.query({"status":"complete"}, function(tabs){
     //Disable all browser actions using chrome.browserAction.disable(integer tabId)
});
```

Let me know if you need more information.